# iframe-like within specific id or class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

On iframe, it show full page.

But I want an iframe-like which showing only within specific id or class.

(So, it must be not the usual iframe. I think javascript is the closest solution to this.)

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do.  Please type in some more explanation.

Comment: i dont want the iframed page showed top-left like usual iframe, but only specific area, with other area removed

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, this doesn't have much to do with the Iframe itself, but more with your selectively setting some parts of your page to visible or invisible, depending on how the page is called?

You could make your page modal, for example by adding a querystring parameter ?viewmode=full or ?viewmode=reduced and then your page would only show certain areas depending on the value of this parameter. In your Iframe you'd set it to viewmode reduced to only see those areas you want to see.

As to how to show only specific areas, you can either do this server-side (hide those Panels that you don't want to see) or client-side with jQuery (show only those divs that have class X). It depends on the structure of your specific page which solution is going to be easier for you.